# Draw my name in python

Tags: python, graphics, line

I have to create a function to draw my name in python. Need some help here as I am really new to python. The name must use the graphics.py library so I will import graphics

I need to create a function like so:

```
DrawUpperCaseR(window,location1,blue)
```

I think I would need to define the function as:

```
def DrawUpperCaseR(window,location1, red):
    location1 = (point1, point2)
```

then my main would be something like:

```
def main():
    win = GraphWin('Name', 320, 240) 
    DrawUpperCaseR(window,location1, blue)
```

Any help pushing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `graphics.py`?

Comment: I suspect `graphics.py` is the [John Zelle graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/) library.

Comment: [Text methods](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node10.html) of that library seems like a good place to start then. If you are allowed to use them, instead of manually constructing the letters from lines.

Comment: We have to use functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a function and draw my initials based from initial xy coordinates 
    def drawUpperCaseD(win, location1)
    x = location1.getX()
    y = location1.getY()
    d1 = Line(Point(x,y), Point(x, y+3)).draw(win)
    return d1

```
def main();
win = GraphWin(320,240)
location1 = (1,1)
drawuppercaseD(win,location)

main()
```

Something similar to this, I was typing from memory, essentially we had to build our initials from points in a window from parameters passed from main.